# QT - Navigation Control

Tags: qt

Is there any navigation control in QT like iPhone? is it possible to develop ?

Please help me.

Comment: I have an iPhone and I don't know what you're talking about; I'm probably not ther only one. What is the navigation control?

Comment: refer please : 1)http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uinavigationcontroller-by-example.aspx 2)http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/navigationcontroller-application-in-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

probably if what you mean navigation side bar, this open source gui code based on Qt may help [link](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/)! -- wwWidgets, particularly the task panel widget.